# Problem converting vcc ver 6 to vcc 2010 express

Tags: visual-c++

I have just installed vcc 2010 express on Win 7 / 64 bit machine.

I am converting a project from vc6 to vcc 2010 express, and nothing happens - ie, no action is performed, no error messages displayed.

Is there a separate tool I can use, or something else I am missing?

edit:  - after loading .dsw:

```
x:\Example Module\ExampleModule.dsp : error  : Project upgrade failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [link](http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/584501/converting-vc6-dsp-files-with-vc2010-express) it seams it's known issue that will be resolved in some future Visual Studio. One workaround is to use Visual Studio 2008 to convert the project into intermediate version.

Comment: Thanks.  I had vcc2008 on another machine and was able to convert to 2008 then to 2010.  Now all I have to do is figure out how to compile this thing properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same error when doing it in a Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt?

```
X> devenv /Upgrade "Example Module.dsw"
```

Make sure that all of the files in the workspace are checked-out for editing (not marked as read-only)

```
X> attrib -r *.* /s
```